# Github Windows Client merge failure

Tags: windows, github, git-merge

We currently have 2 developers working on a project and use Github and the Github-Client for Windows.

### Our Github branches:

1. master
2. pre_production (clone from master)
3. dev_1 (clone from master)
4. dev_2 (clone from master)

The basic idea being, 2 branches for development, which are then pushed to pre_production and then tested in the pre_production server; then when everything is working fine, pushed to master.

I'm not sure if the above is the correct workflow, as I'm pretty new to Git. Anyway, we were testing the workflow and we did the following steps:

### On Dev1 machine

1. Made a change in local dev_1, synced with remote dev_1
2. Merged local dev_1 into local pre_production (since pre_production hasn't changed yet)
3. Synced local pre_production with remote pre_production.
4. Merged local pre_production into local dev_1
5. Synced local_dev1 with remote dev_1

### On Dev2 machine

1. Made changes in local dev_2, synced with remote dev_2
2. Switched to local pre_production and synced with remote pre_production
3. Merged local dev_2 into local pre_production
4. Synced local pre_production with remote pre_production
5. Merged local pre_production into local dev_2

It worked fine up to this point. Then when we tried to merge the changes made by dev2 into dev1 it failed while syncing local dev_1 with remote dev_1 (at step 5).

As we are new to Git, it would be great to have some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like I found the answer to my question.

In step 5, instead of trying to 'sync' the local_dev and the remote_dev, we simply forced a push to the remote_dev. We can do this safely as the local_dev will have the latest changes and not the remote one.

Did it using the below command:

**git push git_url local_branch:remote_branch**

Hope this helps someone.